# CSS: File Input - target the text that says "no file chosen"

Tags: html, forms, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that is using Bootstrap 3. I want to have a file input that is styled more nicely than the browser default.

How can I target the text that says "No file chosen"? I want to vertically center it.

[image]

Comment: If you're voting to close, please leave a comment regarding why :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a div to assign to file input:
HTML :

```
<input type="file" name="the_file" style="display:none;" />
<div style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; padding:5px; background: #eeeeee;" id="file-browse" >choose file</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$('#file-browse').click(function(){
 $fileInput = $('input[name=the_file]');

 var myFile;
 $fileInput.click();
 $fileInput.change(function(e)
 {
  myFile = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(myFile);
 });
});
```